# Why is font in a button flatter than in a div?

Tags: html, css, input, font-size

[image]

Look at these buttons. On the left you can see a styled div, but on the right is an input button. Font-sizes are the same, but in the button the font is like it's flattened a little bit. Look at the letters "k" and "w".

What do I have to do to make this font not flatten?

Comment: What browser is that screenshot from?

Comment: Create a test case on jsFiddle.net or publish something live please.

Comment: By the way, both "On left you.." and "but on the left.."  :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the `<button>` actually using a different font than the `<div>`? Or is it bold?

Set `font-family` and `font-weight` to identical values for the `<div>` and the `<button>`, and see if they look the same then.